# css display property not working correctly in IE7. IE7 bug I suspect

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

My problem is with the menu. There is only 1 .active class li element in the menu yet .active style applies itself to every li element in the menu to the right of it's location. This problem is only in IE7. So far I've tried changing the selectors, modifying the html, and I even re-arrange the rules hoping that it would be resolved.

**Link:**
http://julianjosephs.com/FQBM_NEW/

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span>ACCUEIL </span></a><img src="images/menu-item-bg-hover-texture-2.png" alt="" class="radial_gradient" /><img src="images/menu-divider.png" alt="" class="menu_divider" /></li>
      <li><a href="Historique.html"><span>HISTORIQUE </span></a><img src="images/menu-item-bg-hover-texture-2.png" alt="" class="radial_gradient" /><img src="images/menu-divider.png" alt="" class="menu_divider" /></li>
      <li><a href=""><span>EVENEMENTS </span></a><img src="images/menu-item-bg-hover-texture-2.png" alt="" class="radial_gradient" /><img src="images/menu-divider.png" alt="" class="menu_divider" /></li>
      <li><a href="ListeClubs.html"><span>CLUBS MMA</span></a><img src="images/menu-item-bg-hover-texture-2.png" alt="" class="radial_gradient" /><img src="images/menu-divider.png" alt="" class="menu_divider" /></li>
      <li><a href=""><span>COMBATTANTS </span></a><img src="images/menu-item-bg-hover-texture-2.png" alt="" class="radial_gradient" /><img src="images/menu-divider.png" alt="" class="menu_divider" /></li>
      <li><a href="Boutique.html"><span>BOUTIQUE MMA</span></a><img src="images/menu-item-bg-hover-texture-2.png" alt="" class="radial_gradient" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .menu {
    margin:0;
    width: 963px;
    float:left;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 64px;
    background: url(images/menu-bg.png) no-repeat;
}
.menu ul {
    text-align: left;
    padding:0px 23px 0 35px;
    *padding:0px 6px 0 16px; /* IE7 hack */
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    border:0;
    float:left;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 917px;
}
.menu ul li { float:left; margin:0; padding:0; border:0; height: 64px; position:relative; }
.menu ul li a { float:left; margin:0; padding:21px 0 0 0;  color:#fff; font:normal 16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-decoration:none; height: 64px; position:relative; z-index:3; background:transparent; }
.menu ul li a span { padding:20px 23px; }
.menu ul li a:hover { background: transparent; }
.menu ul li a:hover span {

}
.menu ul li a.active { }

.menu ul li a.active span {  }

.menu ul li .radial_gradient{
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display:none;
    z-index:-1;
}

.menu ul li:hover .radial_gradient{
    display:block;
}

.menu ul li.active .radial_gradient{
    display:block;
}

.menu ul li .menu_divider{
    position:absolute;
    right: -6px;
    top: -4px;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: compare IE7 to IE8, I'm sure the menu looks much darker

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the following styles:

```
.menu ul li .radial_gradient {
    display:none;
}
.menu ul li.active .radial_gradient {
    display:block;
}
```

with:

```
.menu ul li .radial_gradient {
    visibility:hidden;
}
.menu ul li.active .radial_gradient {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the image at URL images/menu-item-bg-hover-texture-2.png is taking 917 px. Try setting some width in pixels for this image instead of setting width as 100%.

Here is what I did.
Opened developer tools and changed widht of the above said image to some 50 px. It worked.

Comment: this seems to be the problem, but your solution would involve me or any other developer setting a fixed width for each menu item. there must be some way to get the img to respect the constraints of its relative parent div.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @JQone, your problem is with the placement of the image in the `li` tags.

A better solution would be to use background images - that way they could still fill 100% of the width and you would only have to include the image once. So your CSS would become:

```
.menu ul li:hover, .menu ul li.active {
    background: url('images/menu-item-bg-hover-texture-2.png') repeat-x 0 0 transparent;
}
```

And you could remove the respective `.radial_gradient` CSS and the `<img />` from the HTML.

Comment: background-images were my original solution but then I realized that repeat-x could not cut it for a radial gradient and background-size was not an option as I needed support for IE7 and IE8 hence I had to use images. i soloved the problem by using a % width on the li for IE7 only

Comment: Ah, that is a good reason not to use them. Rather than using a fixed width on your `li` tags, could you not use `overflow: hidden` instead?

Comment: i'm not following. how would overflow: hidden help with a radial gradient background for individual menu items?

Comment: It wouldn't - but the problem was that the image took the size `100%` from the `ul` rather than the `li`. I was suggesting adding `overflow: hidden` to the `li` element might have been a tidier way of preventing the image flowing over the `li` siblings. It still wouldn't work great with the radial image but setting the widths looks a bit odd when I check it in IE7.